# My Elasticity Doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

I had a question on elasticity which looked something like this.

[image]{: .center}

We have small beads of mass say $m$ and Mass of rod say $M$. Now we need to find the extension in the rod after the beads collide with the the perfectly elastic rubber. Given that it rotates with angular speed $\omega$ and

$\text{Young's Modulus} = Y$ and $\text{Area}=A$ also length of the rod is $L$. [And if you need more variable you can take it. I think the given variables are enough]

No friction is there between the beads.

Now see my solution.

---

**Plan**

We have a rotating rod. So we will find out the extension for rotation (Say $x_{1}$) and for the collision (say $x_{2}$).

So is it  that we need to find out $x_{1}+x_{2}$.

Now we can find $x_{1}$ easily as follows.

Lets take a differential portion of the rod as $dx$.

Now the mass of the differential mass = $dm = \lambda dx$

As rod is uniform we have $\lambda = \dfrac{M}{L}$

$\implies dm= \dfrac{M}{L} dx$.

Now our Stress= $\dfrac{Force}{Area}$

$\implies Stress = \dfrac{dm \omega^2 x}{A}$

$\implies Stress = \dfrac{M \omega^2 dx}{AL}$

$\implies \frac{Stress}{Strain} = Y$

$\implies \dfrac{M \omega^2 x^2 dx}{YAL} = d(\Delta x)$

Integrating from $\frac{-L}{2} \rightarrow \frac{+L}{2}$ we get

$\implies \Delta x = \dfrac{M \omega^2 L^2}{12AY} = x_{1}$

---

Now we have the $x_{2}$ part.

For $x_{2}$,Can we say that the force exerted by each mass on the rod is the force with each hits the elastic surface, $m \omega^2 \dfrac{L}{2}$ and then

$F= 2 m \omega^2 \frac{L}{2}$

$\implies \Delta x_{2} = \dfrac{m \omega^2 L^2}{2YA}$

So We can take $x_{1}+x_{2} = \dfrac{M \omega^2 L^2 + 6m \omega^2 L^2}{12YA}$

**But i am confused if i can take the sum or if the beads play any role in extension or not.**

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Physics SE. Please note that we do not provide solutions for homework-like questions here.

Comment: That's true, although it seems like what's really being asked here is whether it's valid to add $x_1$ and $x_2$. If so, that looks like an example of a specific conceptual question which is allowed by our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714).

Comment: @flaudemus I don't think the OP is asking for someone just to provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: @flaudemus Sir, As others are saying, I am not asking for solution. I worked out the question and I'm asking a conceptual doubt. I guess its allowed?